# How can I reference different <script> tags on my html page in Visual Studio in a local dev vs. deployed sense?

Tags: azure, optimization, visual-studio-2013, gruntjs

I would like to know how can I reference different javascript files on my html page in Visual Studio which reflect the appropriate environment - local dev vs. deployed (on Azure)

For example, when I am developing locally, I have something like this at the bottom of my `<body>` tag (abbreviated dummy names used)

```
<script src="js/local-1.js"></script>
<script src="js/local-2.js"></script>
<script src="js/local-3.js"></script>
```

When I am ready for deployment, I leverage grunt to concat and minify these files. The script I reference will now look as such

```
<script src="js/concat-and-minified.min.js"></script>
```

This works fine, but I am left with the manual process of ensuring I deploy the correct html page with the deployed script reference, then when interested in local development, I change it back

Surely you can see this is tedious and I think qualifies as an unnecessary step, but I am unable to find a way to achieve this.

So, is there a way to select which `<script>` tags exist on my html page depending on the environment of the site? Furthermore, is this primarily even an IDE consideration, or am I missing some other factor?

### Additional details

Though this is in Visual Studio, the front end project is strictly Angular with a single page html file, so any sort of MVC bundling or `.cshtml` if/else logic is not applicable

Comment: Try [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin)

Comment: @Vishwanath thank you for your comment. This actually looks like something very useful that may be just what I need. I'll have to find some time to look into this fully but I'll be sure to get back with my findings

Comment: @salniro -- check out this answer, it may help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29504689/573634